# Fire Effect opengl iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

Hello any one knows a good tutorial where i can find a pointer to fire/flame effects on the iphone. i know i will have to use opengl but got no clue where to start.

Cheers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a [link to a page that has a particle effect tutorial](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/particle_engine_using_triangle_strips/21001/).  This site use to have a fire effect article but the link was removed.  This answer use to have the old link.

Comment: Here's a link to another particle effect tutorial on the same site.  I couldn't dig around for the other fire effect demo but maybe try looking around to see if you can find that one.http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/particle_engine_using_triangle_strips/21001/

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need a particle engine for this. If you wish to learn to create such effects yourself, it might be tough. You can instead use other frameworks like [cocos2d for iPhone](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/). But if you want to do it in pure openGl, search on the lines of 'particle engine / particle generation on iphone' on stackoverflow or even google. You'll get many good pointers. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

[COCOS2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) has a great particle emitter you can use. You can also try Corona for iPhone which is great.